# SQL | Получить топ 5 из бд

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть столбцы: message_guild_id, message_author_id, message_channel_id, message_id.
Каждое сообщение 1 запись в таблице.
Как можно получить топ 5 авторов сообщений, сортированных по количеству?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT message_author_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY message_author_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Если количество для 5-го и 6-го совпадают (а также и других - в любую сторону), то будут выведены случайные записи из всех, имеющих количество, одинаковое с количеством для 5-й записи. В таком случае надо либо расширить выражение сортировки (например, добавить 2-й уровень, по имени), либо вывести более чем 5 записей.

Comment: Спасибо, всё просто и понятно